How to display LiveCharts2 Chart in Blank App, Packed with WAP (WinUI 3 In Desktop) template?
I'm trying to use LiveCharts2 in a WinUI 3 application, but the chart does not appear.
I followed the Installation and first chart Article to try building a WinUI3 window that shows the charts.
I've ensured that my project builds without errors or warnings.
However, the chart does not appear when I run the application.

Here is my setup:
Installed NuGet packages:

LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView.WinUI(2.0.0-rc2.1)
Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools(10.0.22621.756)
Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK(1.5.240428000)

ViewModel.cs (The class contains the Series)
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using LiveChartsCore;
using LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView;

namespace WinUI3_Chart_240604_WAP
{
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public ISeries[] Series { get; set; } = new ISeries[]
        {
            new LineSeries<double>
            {
                Values = new double[] { 2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 4, 6},
                Fill = null,
            }
        };
    }
}

MainWindow.xaml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Window
    x:Class="WinUI3_Chart_240604_WAP.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:WinUI3_Chart_240604_WAP" 
    xmlns:lvc="using:LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView.WinUI"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <!-- xmlns:local="using:App3" didn't work -->
    
    <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="500" Height="500">
        <StackPanel.DataContext>
            <local:ViewModel/>
        </StackPanel.DataContext>

        <lvc:CartesianChart x:Name="Chart" Series="{Binding Series}"></lvc:CartesianChart>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>

MainWindow.xaml.cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using LiveChartsCore;
using LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView;

namespace WinUI3_Chart_240604_WAP
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty window that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            //stackPanel.DataContext = new ViewModel();
            //Chart.Series = new ViewModel().Series;
        }

    }
}

I searched and I didn't find any question that has analogous situation.
I tried using other ways to bind the data, but it didn't work, neither.
The example (and other questions I found) use Window.DataContext property like this:
<Window x:Class="WinUISample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:local="using:App3"
    xmlns:lvc="using:LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView.WinUI">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <lvc:CartesianChart
        Series="{Binding Series}">
    </lvc:CartesianChart>

</Window>

I didn't find that in my project, so I put it into StackPanel.

I am new to LiveCharts2 and WinUI 3, any advice on how to resolve this issue or improve my setup would be appreciated!

You should not edit your question to include the solution. Instead post it as an asnwer.

I found out the answer by looking in their examples:

Need to use Border to limit the area of the chart.
Use Grid instead of StackPanel.
Put the chart in the Page and set the Background to Transparent.

Below are the codes:
<Page
    x:Class="WinUI3_Chart_240604_WAP.HomePage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:WinUI3_Chart_240604_WAP"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:lvc="using:LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView.WinUI"
    Background="Transparent">
    <Page.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel/>
    </Page.DataContext>

    <Grid Width="500" Height="500">
        <Border>
            <lvc:CartesianChart x:Name="Chart" Series="{Binding Series}"></lvc:CartesianChart>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Page>


Please add the content into the answer instead of editing it into the question
